# php function ShellFolder and an AND link

Tags: php, regex, function, shell, grep

I found a code with `function ShellFolder($source, $search1, $search2){$shellBefehl...` with `egrep`. Works so far quite well. But now I have a problem, since the searched text files often contain the same terms. Now I would like to link two search terms with each other which must be found in a text file. This is my code:

```
<?php
function ShellFolder($source, $search1, $search2){
    $shellBefehl = "egrep -o -w -l -a --directories=recurse '$search1' '$search2' $source";
    exec($shellBefehl, $var);
    return $var;
}

//$source = 'grep.txt';
$source = './ordner/daten';
$search1 = $this->item->title;
$search2 = $extraField->value;
$var = ShellFolder($source, $search1, $search2);

$myResult = print_r($var, true);

$text = $myResult;
$text_ohne = substr($myResult, 19);
$insgesamt = $text_ohne;
$insgesamt_neu=substr($insgesamt,0,-3);
echo ($search1);
echo ($search2);
$lines = file("$insgesamt_neu");

foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo($line);
}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

## Grep

It is possible to pass multiple patterns to Grep via `-E` option, for instance. But Grep will search for *any* of the patterns.

If you want to join the search patterns with a logical AND, then Grep is not convenient as it doesn't support logical AND. It is possible to simulate AND with a pattern like `pattern1.*pattern2`, if `pattern1` is supposed to precede `pattern2`:

```
$patterns = ['pattern1', 'pattern2'];
$dir = escapeshellarg($dir);
$pattern = escapeshellarg(implode('.*', $patterns));
$command = "egrep -o -w -l -a -r $pattern $dir";
exec($command, $output, $exit_status);
```

Or `pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1` for any order. But for the generic case the pattern is suboptimal. In other words, Grep is not appropriate for the generic case, and you should use another tool.

## AWK

There is a [portable way to search for multiple patterns using AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55391): `awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && ... ' file`. However, AWK accepts a single file, and you will have to iterate the directory manually and apply the command to each file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Searches for lines matching all regexp patterns.
 *
 * @param string $dir Path to directory with text files
 * @param array $patterns AWK patterns without regexp markers ('/')
 * @return array Files matching all patterns
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
function grepDir($dir, array $patterns, callable $callback) {
  if (!$patterns) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid patterns");
  }

  // Build command as awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && ... path-to-file'
  $awk_script = '/' . implode('/ && /', $patterns) . '/';
  $awk_script = escapeshellarg($awk_script);
  $command_format = "awk $awk_script %s";

  try {
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));

    $it->rewind();
    while ($it->valid()) {
      if (!$it->isDot()) {
        $file_path = $it->key();
        $command = sprintf($command_format, $file_path);
        $output = null;
        exec($command, $output, $exit_status);

        if ($exit_status) {
          trigger_error("Command failed: $command");
          continue;
        }

        if ($output) {
          $callback($file_path, $output);
        }
      }

      $it->next();
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage());
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$dir = '.';
$patterns = [ '456', '123' ];

grepDir($dir, $patterns, function ($file_path, array $output) {
  printf("File: %s\nLines:\n%s\n--------\n",
    $file_path, implode(PHP_EOL, $output));
});
```

*Sample Output*

```
File: ./file1
Lines:
123 sdfsf 456
456 & 123
--------
File: ./test/file1
Lines:
456123
```

## PHP

The example above can easily be converted to a pure PHP solution (without calling the shell commands). You can read the file line by line and test if the line matches the patterns using `preg_match()` according to the logic of your application:

```
$patterns = ['456', '123'];

$file = 'file1'; // Replace with $it->key() in the example above
if (! $fp = fopen('file1', 'r')) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to open file $file");
}

while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
  $matches = true;
  foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    // You might want to quote the pattern, if it isn't supposed to be
    // interpreted as a regular expression:
    // $pattern = preg_quote($pattern, '/');
    if (!preg_match("/{$pattern}/", $line)) {
      $matches = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if ($matches) {
    echo "Line $line matches all patterns\n";
  }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: @UweJansen, please accept the answer, if it solves the problem